# 'An error occurred submitting the question'

Tags: support

I'm getting 'An error occurred submitting the question' on the CiviCRM StackExchange site. Can a CiviCRM StackExchange site admin check this out?

Answer (score 1):

never mind - I was just able to post the question after completing a captcha